# Change the Webcam Dimensions in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, webcam, dimension

I need to resize my Webcam frame size in order to add a text box at the bottom. However, whenever I change the Dimensions, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect dimension [1280x600] possible ones are [176x144] [320x240] [640x480] [1280x720]
```

Here is my code right now:

```
else {
    Dimension[] nonStandardResolutions = new Dimension[] {
        WebcamResolution.HD720.getSize() // Add HD resolution
};


webcam.setCustomViewSizes(nonStandardResolutions);
//webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.HD720.getSize());
webcam.setViewSize(new Dimension(1280, 600));
webcam.open(); // this call will throw a WebcamException if it is in use, taken care of below
webcamPanel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
add(webcamPanel);
cameraInUse = false;
cameraNotDetected = false;
return; // Return as soon as the first available camera is found
```

How can I change the Dimensions without getting the error?

Comment: The error seems to me to indicate you cannot use the sizes provided. I would recommend using one of the ones it lets you (e.g. 1280 x 720).

Comment: Yes, it works if I use one of those sizes. However, I need to resize the vertical dimension in order to fit a text box at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess because I have not worked with a webcam using Java before.

Below is an example, but here is a sample code you can try to implement.

```
    Dimension[] nonStandardResolutions = new Dimension[] { 
        WebcamResolution.PAL.getSize(), 
        WebcamResolution.HD720.getSize(), 
        new Dimension(2000, 1000), 
        new Dimension(1000, 500), 
    }; 

    // your camera have to support HD720p to run this code 
    Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault(); 
    webcam.setCustomViewSizes(nonStandardResolutions); 
    webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.HD720.getSize());
```

Although it seems like the only difference between this and your code seems to be the WebcamResolution.HD720.getSize(). Try adding more dimensions to your nonstandard dimension.

https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture/src/example/java/CustomResolutionExample.java